# Php code reloading Google Fusion Table

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Fusion Tables map that uses a dropdown menu to select points based on a column.

The map works fine until I tried getting fancy.  I tried to use the php API to simply display the selected dropdown value. This works, but the map reloads. Is there any way to avoid the map and form reloading?

As you can tell I'm a bit new to PHP, so please forgive me if I'm unclear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#map_canvas { width: 500px; height: 400px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

var layer;
var tableid = xxxxxx;

function initialize() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.98610025220408, -76.85897827148438),
zoom: 10,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid);
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'lat' FROM " + tableid);
layer.setMap(map); 
}

function changeMap() {
var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value.replace("'", "\\'");
if(searchString == "") {
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'lat' FROM " + tableid);
return;
}
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'lat' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Unit' = '" + searchString + "'");
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize();">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<label>Unit </label>
<select class="dropdown" id="searchString" name="searchString">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Ft Chaplin">Ft Chaplin</option>
<option value="Ft Davis">Ft Davis</option>
<option value="Ft Stanton">Ft Stanton</option>
<option value="Lower">Lower</option>
<option value="Middle">Middle</option>
<option value="Nash Run">Nash Run</option>
<option value="Piney Run">Piney Run</option>
<option value="Stickfoot">Stickfoot</option>
<option value="Upper">Upper</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="mapit"   onClick=" changeMap();" name="submit" value="Map it!"  align="middle">
</form>
</div>
<?php

include('../maps/client_login/clientlogin.php');
include('../maps/client_login/sql.php');
include('../maps/client_login/file.php');
$tableid = xxxxxx;
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$token = ClientLogin::getAuthToken($username, $password);
$ftclient = new FTClientLogin($token);

$condition = $_POST["searchString"];


echo "These Projects are in ".$condition."";
?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The button:

```
<input type="submit" class="mapit"   onClick=" changeMap();" name="submit" value="Map it!"  align="middle">
```

submits the form and reloads the page.

Replace it with a button:

```
<button class="mapit" onclick="changeMap()">Map It!</button>
```

Comment: good suggestion, but it still reloads. I"m guessing it has something to do with the <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

Comment: That seems odd, since that button alone does not submit the form. You could chose to get rid of the form and button elements completely and add the following to the select tag: onchange="changeMap()". Maybe there's something else, not in your example above, that is responsible for the actual submit of the form?